# Azure DevOps Pipeline not finding edmx resources

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops, msbuild, resx, edmx

I have a .Net Core 3.1 MSTest project that calls a separate class library that connects to my database, which was done database-first so I have a .edmx file. It all runs fine locally, but when I push it out to my Azure DevOps Pipeline I start getting a `Unable to load the specified metadata resource.` exception. I've tested this out by putting in a bit of code to print out all the resources in the assembly

```
var resources = (Assembly with EDMX).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
System.Console.WriteLine("There are " + resources.Length + " resources in the assembly");
foreach (var resource in resources)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(resource);
}
```

The result on my local computer prints out what I expect

```
There are 3 resources in the assembly
Model.csdl
Model.msl
Model.ssdl
```

However, the same run on my Pipeline shows 0 resources

```
There are 0 resources in the assembly
```

My build process locally and on my pipeline are the exact same

```
task: PowerShell@2
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
  & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyProject\MyProject.sln
  dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyProject -include ('*.csdl', '*.msl', '*.ssdl') -recurse
  & "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyProject\Project.Tests\Project.Tests.csproj
```

Just to make sure the resources actually exist on my Azure Build agent I've added that 2nd powershell command to find my .csdl, .msl, and .ssdl files, and sure enough they **do** exist

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
-a----        5/30/2020   3:54 PM          30772 Model.csdl                                                   
-a----        5/30/2020   3:54 PM          10993 Model.msl                                                    
-a----        5/30/2020   3:54 PM          23351 Model.ssdl
```

These files are located in **$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\MyProject\Project.Models\obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed**

And the property looks to be correctly set in my .csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <EntityDeploy Include="ProjectModels.edmx">
          <Generator>EntityModelCodeGenerator</Generator>
          <LastGenOutput>ProjectModels.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </EntityDeploy>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I don't use .edmx database designs often, so I'm unfamiliar on how it is suppose to handle the resources, are they suppose to get compiled into the assembly, or are they just loaded at runtime? My build process both locally and in my Pipeline both show:

```
Skipping target "EntityDeployNonEmbeddedResources" because it has no outputs.
EntityDeployEmbeddedResources:
Processing 1 EDMX files.
Starting to process input file 'ProjectModels.edmx'.
Finished processing input file 'ProjectModels.edmx'.
Finished processing 1 EDMX files.
```

Not sure what that indicates, but since it occurs on both I'm assuming its not part of the issue. The only other difference that I can think of is my Azure Pipeline uses Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, while my local build uses Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Any ideas on what I can do to get these resources to load on my Pipeline build?

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue with MSBuild task(Not use Powershell task), would you please check if it works fine with MSBuild task? And where is error comes from? The build or the dotnet test? Please share some detailed error log for that error.

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between the MSBuild task and the Powershell Task calling msbuild.exe. The result is the same for both. I suppose it could be a dotnet test issue. I'm not too sure what additional error logging I can collect. The issue is is still Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() returning 0 when running on the pipeline. I'll see if I can find some additional debugging to do

Comment: It just appears to me that the edmx resource files aren't actually getting embedded into the assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Pipeline not finding edmx resources

This issue should comes from the dotnet test.

AFAIK, dotnet cli does not support embed edmx resources. These types of files are supported in MSBuild props/targets that don't ship in the CLI and only ship in full framework VS.

You could check [this ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8932) for some more details.

And the remaining work for this is already tracked at [dotnet/ef6#231](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/231).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The 'workaround' suggests to use msbuild to compile the assembly instead of dotnet CLI, but as my question suggests I'm already using msbuild and still not finding the resources in the assembly

Comment: @DillonDrobena, The error comes from the msbuild? Or the dotnet test? As far as I know, dotnet test contains dotnet build, would you please check the error comes from which command line?

Comment: There are no command line errors. The issue is the version of msbuild on my devops build agent produces an assembly that does not contain my edmx resources. I'm using dotnet test as a way to check if I can find the resources in the assembly at runtime. Does dotnet test recompile the assemblies? Or does it use the assemblies compiled in my previous build step? Is there another way to check what is contained in my compiled assembly on my build agent?

Comment: So I see that the docs seem to suggest that dotnet test DOES recompile my assemblies, which I can see why that would be a problem

Comment: Once I changed to use vstest.console.exe instead of dotnet test, my issue was resolved